# How to create folder tree by reading file name

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have a requirement where I need to read all files from remote location.
Files stored in remote location will be in format of `categoryName.categoryName.categoryNname.documentNname.extension`
E.g.:   `Interest Calculation Info.2015.October.001-00-232-232.pdf`
I need to read all file names and create folder structure as per below format:

```
Interest Calculation Info
     |--2015  
         |---October
               |--001-00-232-232.pdf
```

There might be various files which may have same categories, those needs to be grouped in same category folder.
What is best possible solution for it?

Comment: show your efforts.... how much did you research ..

Comment: Are you asking about tree-like data structure or about visualizing this tree using some UI component? Or you just want to create such folders on your local filesystem?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes,I don't want to create file system just want to show tree-like structure on JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, **including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories**. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

```
String myString = "Interest Calculation Info.2015.October.001-00-232-232.pdf";
String extension = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf('.'));
String filename = myString.substring(0,myString.lastIndexOf('.')).replace(".", File.separator) + extension;
String startFolder = "C:";

File file = new File(startFolder, filename);
file.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Note that last dot (before `.pdf`) must be preserved.

Comment: umm... really... wil make a patch... :)